# Multiple preact-router routes rendered at the same time in SSR (on Vercel)

Tags: preact, vercel, preact-router

If you go to my Preact app on https://startupguide.vercel.app/ and click “Name Generator”, you will see only the Name Generator form (as it should be). But if you go to https://startupguide.vercel.app/namegenerator and refresh the page (to get SSR page), you see first the Name Generator form, AND the Start page underneath(!).

This is how I have set up my Preact routes:

```
import { Router } from 'preact-router'

import Start from './pages/Start'
import NameGenerator from './pages/NameGenerator'

const App = ({ prop }) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Start path='/' />
      <NameGenerator path='/namegenerator' />
      <NameGenerator path='/namegenerator/:word1' />
      <NameGenerator path='/namegenerator/:word1/:word2' />
    </Router>
  )
}
export default App
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Show the code where you render your `App`? Actually all startup code and SSR code are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/namegenerator` page isn't actually being server-rendered. If you disable JavaScript and load the page, you'll see that it's just the homepage content. This causes an SSR mismatch, which breaks hydration.

To fix this, you can prerender the namegenerator page by creating a `prerender-urls.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "url": "/",
    "title": "Amazing Startup Guide"
  },
  {
    "url": "/namegenerator",
    "title": "Name Generator – Amazing Startup Guide"
  }
]
```

Then update your `package.json` "build" script to pass that file as `--prerenderUrls`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "preact build --prerenderUrls ./prerender-urls.json",
  ...
}
```

Pre-rendering docs are here: https://preactjs.com/cli/pre-rendering/#multiple-urls-and-custom-data

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think it should be `.json` at the end, right? `"preact build --prerenderUrls ./prerender-urls.json"`

Comment: Ah yep, apologies - was on my phone!

Answer (score 0):

The @JasonMiller's answer is the correct one. But I'll leave mine because it's answers an issue with quite similar symptoms, and can be useful for someone else in the future.

---

You are most probably doing something like

```
render(<App/>, root)
```

while you should do something like:

```
render(<App/>, root, root.firstElementChild)
```

for more details you can read
https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/1060
and
https://github.com/preactjs/preact/issues/24